# ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName not functioning as expected

Tags: powershell

I've got a Function that should take either a collection of Server & database names or server names, and go through the databases and shrink their transaction logs. When I run it passing a collection of server & database names it works fine, when I run it passing just a collection of server names it doesn't function as expected.

I call it like this:

```
@([pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver1\instance"
}) ,
@([pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver2\instance"
}) | Recover-LogSpace
```

I get this messages:

```
Working on database @{SqlServer=sqlserver2\instance}
Connecting to @{SqlServer=sqlserver1\instance}
Working on database @{SqlServer=Tsqlserver1\instance}
```

The Function is:

```
Function Recover-LogSpace
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
[parameter(ParameterSetName='Multiple')]
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ValuefromPipeline=$True,ParameterSetName='Single')]
[string[]]$SqlServer,  
[parameter(ParameterSetName='Single')]
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ValuefromPipeline=$True)]
[string[]]$Database
)
BEGIN {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
}
PROCESS {
    foreach($server in $SqlServer) {
    "Connecting to $server"
    $srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $Server
        if($Database) {
        "Working on database $Database"
        $srv.Databases[$Database] | ?{ $_.Shrink(2,[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ShrinkMethod]'TruncateOnly') }
        }
        else {
        "Working on all databases on server"
        $srv.Databases | ?{ $_.ID -gt "4" -And $_.IsAccessible -eq $True -And $_.ReadOnly -eq $False  } | ?{ $_.Shrink(2,[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ShrinkMethod]'TruncateOnly') }
        }
    }
}
END {
}
```

}

Comment: Remove `ValueFromPipeline=$true` from all of your parameters. If you plan on just passing a server name (not as part of an object) to it then you could keep it on the `$SqlServer` parameter, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: I do want to have the choice of passing Server names along the pipe line for a Function that checks space

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline has an array of arrays of pscustomobjects, not an array of pscustomobjects.

Since the items in the pipelines (the arrays) don't have sqlserver or database properties (the elements in the arrays do, though), the binding by property name doesn't happen and the binding by object does.

Changing the invocation to this makes it work (because you're just passing an array of pscustomobjects)

```
[pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver1\instance"
} ,
[pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver2\instance"
} | Recover-LogSpace
```

Comment: I tried it like that and got Connecting to sqlserver1\instance
Working on database @{SqlServer=sqlserver1\instance}
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: [pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver1\instance"
} ,
[pscustomobject]@{
SqlServer = "sqlserver2\instance"
} | Recover-LogSpace

Comment: @iain - you haven't provided a database property, so $Database is binding to the whole object from the pipeline.

Comment: Mike Shepard - that's the whole point, I want to provide a sqlserver name only. And why & where is it binding ?

Comment: It's binding to the object in the pipeline because you have ValuefromPipeline=$True on the $Database parameter.  If you remove that it will only bind in the pipeline by property (i.e. if the objects have Database properties)

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
The issue was the way I had the parameters declared which created an extraneous parameterset. This works as expected:

```
Function Recover-LogSpace
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[parameter(ParameterSetName='Multiple')]
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ParameterSetName='Single')]
[string[]]$SqlServer,  
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ParameterSetName='Single')]
[string[]]$Database
)
```